# Access .NET webservice inside a local Network in android webapplication

Tags: android, .net, web-services, browser, jsonp

I am writing a Webapplication for a mobile device and I'm currenty stuck with some network issues.
I've been testing the software in Google Chrome (& IE8) and my JSONP connection works just perfect. 
Here is my Code:

```
function GetJSON() {

        var cbSuccess = false;
        $.ajax('http://10.221.5.132:1234/WcfService1/WcfTestService/TimeInfo.json/Test?method=?', {
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (data, text, xhqr) {
                var myObj = $.parseJSON(data);
                alert(myObj.data);
                cbSuccess = true
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $('#ausgabe').html('Error: ' + textStatus + ' - ' + errorThrown); alert("Error");
                cbSuccess = true;
            }
        }
        );
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (!cbSuccess) { alert("connection failed"); }
        }, 5000);
    };
```

When starting my Webapp on an android device this will not work. The Android Phone is inside the same network as the webservice.

Stefan

[Edit 31.10.2011]
Problem Solved.

It appears, that there is a problem with the httpget method with Android 2.3 in combination with the .NET web methods.

By adding:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    type: "POST"
});
```

I can get the code to work. I hope this helps, if you're encountering the same problems.

Comment: You should put your solution as an answer and accept it, that way the question does not look unanswered. Others will then be able to easily see the solution you have come up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears, that there is a problem with the httpget method with Android 2.3 in combination with the .NET web methods.

By adding:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    type: "POST"
});
```

i can get the code to work. I hope this helps, if you're encountering the same problems.